How can we show that this compelx sum of products actually converges to $0$?
I'm evaluating an integral and ended up with the expression $$\sum_{n\ge2}\prod_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\int_0^\infty\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\prod_{\substack{j=1\\j\ne i}}^{n-1}\frac1{\alpha_j-\alpha_i}\right)e^{-\alpha_is}\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha_nu}1_{[0,\;u)}(t-s)f(t-s)\;{\rm d}u\;{\rm d}s,$$ where $(\alpha_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a strictly increasing sequence and $f$ is bounded. I suspect that it is true in general, but my hope is that I can give a criterion on the growth of $(\alpha_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ which ensures that the whole expression is actually $0$. Unfortunately, the expression is quite complex and I have no idea how I can proceed at this point. Any help on this is highly appreciated!
